# C# bool array Convert short array

Tags: c#

How to make irregular `bool[]` to `short[]`

Each is really a bit

E.g.:

```
bool[] bools = new []{true,true};
```

or:

```
bool[] bools = new bool[]{true,false,true,false,...};
```

```
public static short[] BoolArrayToShortArray(bool[] bools)
{
    
}
```

I tried before,But `Bitconverter.ToInt6()` requires two bytes

```
bool[] bools=new bool[]{true,true,true,false,true,false};
List<bool> list=new List<bool>();
list.AddRange(bools);
int ints= bools.Length%16;
for(int i=0;i<16-ints;i++)
    {
        list.Add(false);
     }
     BitArray bits=new BitArray(list.ToArray());
     byte[] bytes= ToByteArray(bits);
     short[] shorts=new short[bytes.Length%16];
     for(int i=0;i<bytes.Length%16;i++)
     shorts[i]= BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes);
```

`true=bit`

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the length of the bool array will always be a multiple of 16? Is the first bool in the array the MSB or LSB of the first short?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the OP's question is straightforward (it doesn't need more details or clarity) - I feel the only thing missing is demonstrating whatever research they've done...

Comment: No guarantee, so if it is not enough 16bit, add zero，it is LSB

Comment: @Dai I don't think it's clear. @snow_FFFFFF interpreted it as each bool being turned into one `short`. While @Damien interpreted it as 16 bools being turned into one short. The clarifying comment needs to become part of the question, ideally including expected results of each of the examples in the question.

Comment: Each `true·` is a `bit`

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This uses linq to do it:

```
var shorts = bools.Select(s => s ? (short)1 : (short)0).ToArray();
```